# How to get array values in 'React Native Simple Store'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, arraylist, asyncstorage

How can I get array values in 'React Native Simple Store'?

Here is my code:

```js
const tryList = [];

store.get('shoppingList').then(res => (tryList = {res}));
console.log(tryList);
```

**Output:**

```js
{
  "res": [{
    "price": 10,
    "name": "t-shirt"
  }]
}
```

**Expected output:**

```js
[{
  "price": 10,
  "name": "t-shirt"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
store.get('shoppingList').then(res => (tryList = {res}));
console.log(tryList)
```

See, while you are printing `tryList` it results you an object `{"res": [{"price": 10, "name": "t-shirt"}]}`

But you need to get the value of `res` so for that the way you access the property of an object similarly you have to do here as below.

`console.log(tryList.res)` # this will give your expected result.